# Shortcut key to mimic the INTERNET button which some keyboards have

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-access, citrix

I often use a citrix website to then initiate a Remote Desktop application, in order to then use Remote Desktop Client by citrix to remote in to a work computer.
I always use it full screen, (so that things like Windows key, Start key etc are passed to the remote pc, not my local pc).

however it often happens to where I need to, as I say, "bust out" of my citrix remote pc without closing it.  (there is no way to minimize or restore it).

in the past I've used the Internet button on my keyboard.  It works great - it basically force-activates my local pc and opens the internet, thus busting out of my remote screen.

I've since changed to a simpler keyboard which doesn't have that magic "open internet" button.
I tried making a Google shortcut on my local pc's desktop, and attaching F3 to it, pressing f3 unfortunately did not have any effect...

Can you think of a way to do anything on my local pc which might mimic this effect?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> should do it. It's supposed to only be recognized by Windows, so the guest session shouldn't get it.

Comment: And you might be able to use `CTRL + ALT + INS` if you want it to stick within your remote connection window.